# How to represent a list of entities within a table of the same entity in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called user with an attribute `friendsList` which has to be a list of ids pointing to different users. I really have no clue how to do this using Postgres

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways you can go about this but the most relational and [**normalized**](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) way would be to create a second table called `UserFriendList` with the columns `UserId` and `FriendUserId` which would store one row per `Friend` for each `User`. This table would be one-to-many from `User.Id` to `UserFriendList.UserId` but would also be able to help bridge the join back to the `User` table on `UserFriendList.FriendUserId` to `User.Id` to get all the `User` attributes of the friends. This kind of table is known as a bridge / junction / linking table.

Example query with this design:

```
SELECT 
    User.Id AS UserId, User.FirstName AS UserFirstName, User.LastName AS UserLastName, 
    Friend.Id AS FriendUserId, Friend.FirstName AS FriendFirstName, Friend.LastName AS FriendLastName
FROM User
INNER JOIN UserFriendList
    ON User.Id = UserFriendList.UserId
INNER JOIN User AS Friend
    ON UserFriendList.FriendUserId = Friend.Id
```

Alternatively you can store the `FriendList` column directly on the `User` table as either a comma delimited list or in JSON, but these are both **denormalized** solutions, which will become harder to maintain changes, potentially lead to data redundancy, and will inflate the size of your `User` table which *could* make querying it less efficient.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123533/discussion-on-answer-by-j-d-how-to-represent-a-list-of-entities-within-a-table).